# Regex match with negative look ahead and non greedy

Tags: regex, pcre

source string

```
<html name="abc:///Testers/something.txt" in="abc/Testers/something.txt" loci="123" sap="abcdefgh="/><html name="abc:///needed.txt" src="abc/needed.txt" location="123" sap="rtyghu"/><html name="abc:///Testers/Testers3/Another.txt" in="abc/Testers/Testers3/Another.txt" loci="123" sap="jhkiopjhg"/><html name="abc:///onemore.txt" src="abc/onemore.txt" location="123" sap="dfrtyu"/>
```

How do I match the section starting from `<html name=" not followed by (needed) or (onemore) and ending with />`

So in this string there should be two matches which are

```
<html name="abc:///Testers/something.txt" in="abc/Testers/something.txt" loci="123" sap="abcdefgh="/>
<html name="abc:///Testers/Testers3/Another.txt" in="abc/Testers/Testers3/Another.txt" loci="123" sap="jhkiopjhg"/>
```

I tried this - `<html name=(?!(needed|onemore)).*?"\/>`

It doesnt work as I am confused with the non greedy and negative lookahead stuffs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need is to use a repetition quantifier in addition to putting a restriction on where it should give up traversing:

```
<html\s+name="(?![^"]*(?:needed|onemore))[^>]*>
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/FIoaRS/2)

Comment: Did the OP want to check for blacklisted words only in the `name` attribute or anywhere in the tag?  If the latter, your negative lookahead would also fail.

Comment: I'm not sure either. But if that's the case I'll update answer to include it `<html(?![^>]*(?:needed|onemore))[^>]*>`

Comment: Don't forget the `ending with />` (:

Comment: I'm upvoting you because, believe it or not, I've never had to limit a lookahead in this way +1

Comment: OP isn't *validating* subject string but *matching*. Existence of a slash mark doesn't conflict with given solution. @MateusA.

Comment: I upvoted because your answer is clear and clever, and this part is not a big problem at all. Nevertheless, don't speak for the OP. If he's asking for `ending with />`, probably he does not want [this](https://regex101.com/r/FtBl9h/3) first match. I know what you're trying to say, but you still shouldn't change the matching rules.

Comment: A principle I have found to be useful in solving problems is *What You See Is Not What You Get*. I do what I think is right or can be. I don't see a strict rule in matching HTML tags which end to `/>` but not `>`. I read *...and ending with `/>`* as a declarative sentence which you may read in another way. By the way thank you for up-voting. @MateusA.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the breakdown of your regex `<html name=(?!(needed|onemore)).*?"\/>`

```
<html name=(?!(needed|onemore)).*?"\/>
1) Literal match: <html name=
2) Not followed by: "needed" or "onemore"
3) Lazy grab all: .*?
  Until Literal match: "/>
```

What you need to do is check for needed or onemore with each character grab using another grouping like this `<html name=(?:(?!(needed|onemore)).)*?"\/>`. That will check that "needed" or "onemore" isn't next on each character grab. (I would also recommend using `[^>]` instead of `.` so that you don't need the lazy quantifier.)

However, I would recommend using something like this for your filtering `<html name=([^>no]|n(?!eeded)|o(?!nemore))*>`. Much easier to adapt and less work for the regex engine.